# (keyup) no work when try to splice event.target.value

Tags: javascript

I want to splice number if is value > 12 but no work.

```
   public preventNum(e){ 
        let selectedNumber = e.target.value; 
        if (selectedNumber > 12) { 
            selectedNumber = selectedNumber.slice(0, 1) 
          }
          else {
           console.log('else')
          } 
    }


    <timepicker  
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTime"  
        (keyup)="preventNum($event)" >
```

Why no work ?
When I console.log selectedNumber number is spliced but value in input stay.

If example type in input 15 , i want to splice to 1 number...

I am also try to splice selectedTime but that is DATE type and can't be apply splice on date..

selectedNumber is spliced but on input stay..

Comment: Assuming that `e.target` is a form control, `e.target.value` would be a string not a number if you are using slice because there's a letter in said value, you sholud slice the value first, convert it to a number, then determine if it's above 15.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix datatypes, and getting bad results. Let's take this one piece at a time:

1. `event.target.value`

Although your code sample does not include this part, I am pretty sure that your event is a change or input event from an HTML `<input type="text">`. For most HTML input types, including text inputs, the value will be of type String.

That means this code will give you bad results:

```js
selectedNumber > 12
```

Why? Because inequality operators like `>` and `<` should generally only be used when *both operands* are Numbers (or numerics, like Dates -- which *does not include* string representations of a date). The only time you should ignore this rule is when writing a custom sort function that needs to compare strings. You are not sorting in this sample, so the rule applies.

To fix this, you should convert the raw value from a String to an actual Number, like so:

```js
let selectedNumber = parseInt(event.target.value)
```

(If you want to work with decimals, use `parseFloat` instead.)

2. Don't use `slice` for this

As a practical matter, following my first suggestion will force you to stop using `slice` because Numbers do not have a slice method.

The right fix here depends on what you're trying to accomplish, and I'm not sure what your goal is.

The charitable interpretation of your code sample as written is: "if the number is greater than twelve, keep only the most significant digit."

The rest of your code sample suggests to me that you are trying to do math related to 12-hour clocks, which makes me think the logic I just described is not the only or even best way to accomplish your goal.

I have a hunch that what you're trying to do is figure out whether the user gave you a time that's before or after noon. If that's right, then it is much clearer code and better data design to do something like this:

```js
let isMorning = selectedNumber < 12
let isAfternoon = selectedNumber >= 12
```

If I've misunderstood your goal, feel free to explain your goal in more detail.

---

One more note generally: choose your datatypes carefully. Javascript provides a decent assortment of basic datatypes: Strings, Numbers, Dates, and Boolean. You have to make decisions about how to represent the data that your application needs. You will always get the best results if you choose the native datatype that is the closest logical fit for the data you want.

To illustrate my point, here are some examples of very bad ideas; never do any of these things:

- store a yes/no value as a String, with `1` = yes and `0` = no (Boolean is the correct choice)
- store a quantity as a String, such as `let sheepCount = "5"` (Number is the correct choice)
- store an object ID as a Number, even if it is all digits, such as `rowId = 5` (in Javascript, IDs should always be stored as Strings)